# Getting Invalid Column Name issue with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework in my current project. After deployment of the code to production we started facing the below issues.

> 2019-01-28 13:55:28.5528 UTC+0000 ERROR:
>   DatabaseService.QueryAuthentication
>   System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while
>   executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'GcdId'.    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<>c__11`1.b__11_0(IEnumerable`1
>   sequence)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression
>   expression)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source)

The steps which we followed are below:

1. We generate Entities from Test Db as we don't have access to Prod Db. EF5 is used for generating Entities and we used Database First approach.
2. We create a setup for the application that needs to be deployed.
3. Prod Db was updated with the Db Script. The structure of Prod and Test Db is same in terms of tables and columns.
4. The application was installed on client machine through installer.
5. When the client launch the application the above error pops up even though the column exists in the Table in Db.

Can anyone please guide us what is the root cause of this issue and the possible solution to resolve it.

Comment: Post the code and table schema instead of describing them. Most likely the entity class has a property that doesn't exist in the target table

Comment: "We generate Entities from Test Db " - but there is a missing column in prod.  Well, I guess you have found your problem !

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'GcdId' this column cannot be found? naming difference?

Comment: @Panagiotis, there is a property in both table as well as in mapping. The application is working fine in Test Environment.

Comment: @Neil, the column exists is db

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan, Naming convention is correct and is same in db as well as in code.

Comment: Use SQL Server Profiler to see what Query is sent to the SQL server.

Comment: @Neil, I also wants to check the same but I don't have access to Profiler. It's the Biggest Hurdle for me.

Comment: @ShivangKaul you can log the queries generated by EF. Perhaps you should check the table in production? If the code works in the test environment it probably means production is *not* the same

Comment: @ShivangKaul `as we don't have access to Prod Db` well, you'll have to verify the columns *are* there. Perhaps the DB update script failed or it didn't contain the necessary columns.

Comment: If you don't have access to prod, how can you be sure this 'missing' column is there ?

Comment: I requested the backup of the Prod Db and restored in Test, and it was working.

Comment: @ShivangKaul why don't you post your query and database table?

Answer (score -1):

Check out in the application which function or procedures it shows error, use try catch too.Sometimes Entity framework save enitites with different name.check that too.